# ZeroMQ across Google Compute instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Upon trying to bind ZeroMQ  Socket to google compute **ephemeral IP** result in

**Cannot assign requested address (IOError)**

I think, I get what is the reason for this because the `ifconfig` does not report the **ephemeral IP** in the listing

All it contain **private IP** (which I believe is NAT ip) that google internally uses.

Reference drawn from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/666187/bind-cannot-assign-requested-address)

The Firewall rule for the desired port have be allowed to

```
zeromq-port 0.0.0.0/0   tcp:5437-5438   Apply to all targets
```

Now how does I work around with this and have ZeroMQ communicate across the  across instances.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you only want to bind to the external IP address, and not the internal one?

Comment: If you need to bind your service to external IP you can accomplish this setup using forwarding rules(https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules). Forwarding rules will be assigned an external IP, you can use this IP to bind your service.

Comment: If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue.

Answer (score 1):

[GCE network layer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) will forward packets destined to a particular external IP to the corresponding instance. “Ifconfig” will not list an interface having an external IP. Binding services to all interfaces should work on [most applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759394/zmqerror-cannot-assign-requested-address).